# SharedPreferences automatically save text from TextView without a Save button

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem that should remember-save the text from the TextView that the user inputs through his voice, but I have enabled the Night mode, at the time when the day mode passes into the night mode, the text entered at that moment disappears. I know that it needs to be SharedPreferences, I tried this code, but I can not record anything. I emphasize that there is no Save button. It is necessary to return the text already entered when refreshing the Activity. I ask for help please

```
/*...*/{
    //...
    myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(restoredText)) {
        myText.setText(restoredText);
    }
    //...
}


public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("text", myText.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your activity is getting killed. If this is the case, then you should implement the android activity lifecycle methods onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
  state.putString("text", myText.getText().toString());
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));

}
```